# Making code more efficient by reducing if statements

Tags: c++

I'm making a recipe dispenser program that will print recipes based on:

- The spice level of the food
- The time it takes to cook

I may add more later down the road.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input = "";
    string recipe1 = "A mild recipe that takes 10 mins";
    string recipe2 = "A mild recipe that takes 20 mins";
    string recipe3 = "A medium recipe that takes 10 mins";
    string recipe4 = "a mild recipe that takes 20 mins";

    cout << "Hello to the recipe dispenser 2000" << endl << "I will now begin with some questions to get the perfect recipe for you" << endl << "Do you like your food mild, medium, or hot?" << endl;
    getline (cin, input);
    if(input == "mild")
      cout << "Would you like a recipe that takes 10 or 20 mins?" << endl;
      getline (cin, input);
      if(input == "10" or input == "10 mins")
        cout << recipe1 << endl;
}
```

However the code I have now seems pretty inefficient, as I would have to write out a total of 6 if statements in order to complete the code.

Is there any way to shorten this?
For example by adding some tags or something to each recipe, like `[10, mild]` to `recipe1`, then the code will output the response based on the tags.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Does this compile?

Comment: Your code isn't even correct in the first place. The if statement with the 'or' keyword will always evaluate to true because it's `(input == "10") or ("10 mins")`, what you meant is `(input == "10" or input == "10 mins")`

Comment: `#define or ||` or maybe using a compiler which has a specific extension?

Comment: @adnan_e Fixed, thanks

Comment: change the recipe type from string to map< pair<string,int>,string >

Comment: @JVApen afaik the or keyword is in the [c++ standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) as an alternative to ||

Comment: Also, faster than this? I don't think so, but maybe you could improve ease of read and scalability by using some data structures like `map`

Comment: @IlayaRajaS what effect would this have? Thanks

Comment: @adnan_e: I've learned something new, tnx!

Comment: It's not unusual for a program to have *way* more than 6 if-statements. :-)

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do you have any indication that this is at all an issue? You're doing console IO, the user will never humanly see speed improvements...

Comment: @AmiTavory ,it's not an issue with the program itself, I just want to actually learn some more efficient methods if they exist, sure I can copy and paste each if statement, but then I wouldn't have learnt anything new

Comment: This question has quite a broad scope. There are many ways you could resolve your issue (probably more a maintainability issue than code speed issue). One simple option is a vector of recipe objects each containing the time taken and spice level. You then search the vector after all inputs are done. I'm guessing you'll want to extend this in the future.

Comment: Why do you think if-statements are your bottleneck?

Comment: @YiFei I don't  I'm making this program to learn in the first place :)

Answer (score 5):

```
int main()
{
    string input = "";
    int inp;
    map< string,map<int,string> > recipe;
    recipe["mild"][10]="A mild recipe that takes 10 mins";
    recipe["mild"][20]= "A mild recipe that takes 20 mins";
    recipe["medium"][10]= "A medium recipe that takes 10 mins";

    cout << "Hello to the recipe dispenser 2000" << endl << "I will now begin with some questions to get the perfect recipe for you" << endl << "Do you like your food mild, medium, or hot?" << endl;
    getline (cin, input);
    cout << "Would you like a recipe that takes 10 or 20 mins?" << endl;
    cin>>inp;
    try
    {
        cout<<(recipe.at(input)).at(inp);
    }
    catch(exception &e)
    {
        cerr<<input<<" , "<<inp<<" has not been invented yet!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Pretty elegant use of STL in my opinion. Hope this serves your purpose.
Refer

- For maps : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/
- And http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stlmap.html
- For try catch : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: Cheers dude, this works, on a final note what should I research to actually understand how this works or what you have done?

Comment: `cout<<recipe[input][inp];` -- And if the user enters "cold", you have a small issue here of empty entries being added to the map.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie let me fix that

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work. But it is very specific to this example.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   string input1 = "";
   string input2 = "";
   string recipe1 = "A mild recipe that takes 10 mins";
   string recipe2 = "A mild recipe that takes 20 mins";
   string recipe3 = "A medium recipe that takes 10 mins";
   string recipe4 = "a mild recipe that takes 20 mins";

    cout << "Hello to the recipe dispenser 2000" << endl << "I will now begin    with some questions to get the perfect recipe for you" << endl << "Do you like your food mild, medium, or hot?" << endl;
    getline (cin, input1);
    cout << "Would you like a recipe that takes 10 or 20 mins?" << endl;
    getline (cin, input2);
    cout<< "A " << input1<<" recipe that takes "<<input2<<" mins"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: i guess recipe1,etc are just placeholders

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> recipes = {{"10", "A mild recipe that takes 10 mins"}};
    std::string input;
    getline (std::cin, input);

    try {
        std::cout << recipes.at(input);
    } catch(std::out_of_range& e) { std::cout << e.what();}


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With something like this, I think you can manage lots of spiciness and delays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

size_t index(const string& str, const vector<string>& v)
{
    auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), str);
    if(it != v.end()) {
        return distance(v.begin(), it);
    }
    // else --> not found
}

int main()
{

    string input = "";
    string recipe[] = {"A mild recipe that takes 10 mins",
                       "A mild recipe that takes 20 mins",
                       "A medium recipe that takes 10 mins",
                       "A medium recipe that takes 20 mins"};

    vector<string> spiciness {"mild", "medium", "hot"};
    vector<string> delay {"10", "20"};

    int spi;
    int del;

    cout << "Hello to the recipe dispenser 2000" << endl
         << "I will now begin with some questions to get the perfect recipe for you" << endl
         << "Do you like your food mild, medium, or hot?" << endl;

    getline (cin, input);
    spi = index(input, spiciness);

    cout << "Would you like a recipe that takes 10 or 20 mins?" << endl;
    getline (cin, input);
    del = index(input, delay);

    cout << recipe[delay.size()*spi + del];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK! The best possible solution for this could be using a 2D array.

```
Store all the items that are both mild & 10 min in array[1],
Store all the items that are both mild & 20 min in array[2],
Store all the items that are both medium & 10 min in array[3],
Store all the items that are both medium & 20 min in array[4],
Store all the items that are both hot & 10 min in array[5],
Store all the items that are both hot & 20 min in array[6],
```

Ask for input:

```
int input1,input2;
cout << "Hello to the recipe dispenser 2000" << endl
     << "I will now begin with some questions to get the perfect recipe for you" << endl
     << "Do you like your food 1)mild, 2)medium, or 3)hot?" << endl;
cin>>input1;
cout << "Would you like a recipe that takes 1)10 or 2)20 mins?" << endl;
cin>>input2;
//print array[((input1-1)*2)+input2 ]
```

Done! without if's.